# Thermal equivalent circuit models

Tags: power-electronics, thermal

When I only have two components (for example a Module and a heat sink), what thermal equivalent circuit models (Cauer or Foster) should I use to represent it?

Comment: You should read this https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/application-note/AN11261.pdf

Comment: @Antonio51 I already did but still dont understand. Personally i would use the Cauer model but I only have to components so Im not sure if its the right model